# yarn berry declared in dependencies

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg-v2

I created next js project with yarn berry
and tryed to install `@yarnpkg/sdks vscode`
but the following error has occurred.

[image: error log]

as described in the error installed color-convert but showed same error
I searched the Internet, but it didn't come out.

Comment: Quick solution - don't use yarn berry or disable pnp mode (set `nodeLinker: node-modules`). Long solution - use packageExtensions to fix up all deps (https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#fix-dependencies-with-packageextensions) For example, for your error you'll first need to declare via packageExtensions that ansi-styles is the one that needs color-convert. Then run again, you'll get another error, keep on fixing them.